# Which method of logarithmic transformation is correct to use in linear model?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, logarithm, methodology, logarithmic-series-distribution

I try to do a simple linear model with logarithmic transformation of `y` values. I found that depending on which method I use the results differ and I don't understand why. I used 3 different methods:

1. I `log10`-transformed `y` values and run a linear model: `lm = lm(log10.y ~ x)`

```
    > log10.y = log10(y)
    > lm = lm(log10.y ~ x)
    > summary(lm)

    Call:
    lm(formula = log10.y ~ x)
    
    Residuals:
         Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
    -0.18026 -0.06582  0.01475  0.05069  0.15280 
    
    Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept) 2.5135003  0.4180387   6.013 0.000319 ***
    x           0.0005840  0.0003388   1.724 0.123027    
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    Residual standard error: 0.1142 on 8 degrees of freedom
    Multiple R-squared:  0.2708,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1797 
    F-statistic: 2.972 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.123
```

2. I used raw `y` values and used `log`-transformation within model call: `lm = lm(log(y) ~ x)`

```
    > lm = lm(log(y) ~ x)
    > summary(lm)
    
    Call:
    lm(formula = log(y) ~ x)
    
    Residuals:
         Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
    -0.46187 -0.18506 -0.03391  0.20047  0.40393 
    
    Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
    (Intercept) 5.3713191  1.1063922   4.855  0.00126 **
    x           0.0018070  0.0008967   2.015  0.07864 . 
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    Residual standard error: 0.3021 on 8 degrees of freedom
    Multiple R-squared:  0.3367,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2538 
    F-statistic: 4.061 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.07864
```

3. I used raw `y` values and used `log10`-transformation within model call: `lm = lm(log10(y) ~ x)`

```
> lm = lm(log10(y) ~ x)
> summary(lm)

Call:
lm(formula = log10(y) ~ x)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.20059 -0.08037 -0.01473  0.08706  0.17542 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) 2.3327342  0.4805000   4.855  0.00126 **
x           0.0007848  0.0003894   2.015  0.07864 . 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1312 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3367,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2538 
F-statistic: 4.061 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.07864
```

As you can see, models differ between a model with pre-transformed `y` values `lm = lm(log10.y ~ x)` and log transformation within the models (2nd and 3rd method). Model `lm = lm(log(y) ~ x)` and `lm = lm(log10(y) ~ x)` only differ in intercept and slope, but the overall models are the same which is logical. But I don't understand why there is a difference in whether I first transform data `log10.y = log10(y)` and use it in the model `lm = lm(log10.y ~ x)` or use transformation in the formula directly `lm = lm(log10(y) ~ x`?

I'd be grateful for any help and explanation.

Comment: I don't know why 1 and 3 are different. Those look like they should be the same. #2 is a natural log transformation, which is a lot more commonly used to transform Y.

Comment: Additionally I tried approach #1 and #3 with R's iris data set and their output was the same. So I'm wondering if there is an issue in code not included in your example.

Comment: To make it easier to get help, please provide a minimal reproducible example as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This includes the sample data. In R this is particularly easy with the [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/learn-reprex.html) addin.

Comment: @MichaelWebb thanks for the tipp! I checked the data and it looks like I had `y` and `log10.y = log10(y)` values (n = 100) a the beginning and used mean values of populations for both `mean(y)` and `mean(log10.y)` which gave me 10 values with differences: `>y 
[1] 3.058297 3.168199 3.160605 3.401012 3.278835 3.308509 3.333238 3.239909 3.456366 3.569432`
`> log10.y
 [1] 3.043786 3.043178 3.146205 3.320925 3.275831 3.276134 3.264016 3.237092 3.248434 3.458792`
I think to make it simple and avoid mistakes I should use raw data and use log transformation in the formula. Thanks a lot!